# Spring integration sftp issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, build.gradle, spring-integration-sftp

I am working in a springboot project version 1.5.10.RELEASE.

I am using spring-integration for sftp. Everything works fine for me with the following gradle dependencies

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-core', version: '5.0.5.RELEASE'

compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.3.5.RELEASE"

compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:4.3.5.RELEASE"

compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-sftp', version: '5.0.5.RELEASE'

compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-ftp', version: '5.0.5.RELEASE'
```

I have also integrated prometheus in the module.

```
compile "io.prometheus:simpleclient:${prometheusVersion}"

compile "io.prometheus:simpleclient_hotspot:${prometheusVersion}"

compile "io.prometheus:simpleclient_spring_boot:${prometheusVersion}"

compile group: 'io.prometheus', name: 'simpleclient_servlet', version:prometheusVersion

compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: springVersion
```

I have done all the other requirements for prometheus. But I am not getting prometheus metrics.

All the other services in the project are using prometheus but not using spring integration sftp and prometheus is working for all of them.

I tried debugging and found that updating spring-integration-core to 5.0.6.RELEASE will fix the issue for prometheus but doing this, I keep on getting compile time issue

> error: cannot access CoreSubscriber
>   handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(sftpRemoteDirectory));
>
> class file for reactor.core.CoreSubscriber not found Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 1 error

Please help me with this.

Comment: Spring versionging issues, are you using spring 5.0 with Spring integration's proper version ?

Comment: As mentioned it was working fine as per above config.
As I update it to following, I start facing issues.

compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.0.6.RELEASE"

compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:5.0.6.RELEASE"

compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-sftp', version: '5.0.6.RELEASE'

compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-ftp', version: '5.0.6.RELEASE'

Comment: You need Boot 2.0 for Spring Integration 5.0.

Comment: @GaryRussell I tried. Still the same error

Comment: You must still have mismatched jars; you need to let boot manage the dependencies for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved everything to version 5.0.0.RELEASE. Its working now.